# how to get signing keys for blackberry?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-10, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

[Signing keys for blackberry link](https://www.blackberry.com/SignedKeys/codesigning.html) For BlackBerry 10 apps developed using Android. When I selected the First CheckBox for **BlackBerry Keys Order Form**, it is automatically point to another links are [Sign In to BlackBerry ID](https://blackberryid.blackberry.com/bbid/login/?callbackuri=aHR0cHM6Ly9ibGFja2JlcnJ5aWQuYmxhY2tiZXJyeS5jb20vb3BlbmlkL2F3&authtype=b3Blbmlk&realm=aHR0cHM6Ly9kZXZlbG9wZXIuYmxhY2tiZXJyeS5jb20%3D&requireConfirmedEmail=dHJ1ZQ%3D%3D&locale=ZW5fVVM%3D&openidmode=Y2hlY2tpZF9zZXR1cA%3D%3D&userdata=aHR0cHM6Ly9kZXZlbG9wZXIuYmxhY2tiZXJyeS5jb20vY29kZXNpZ25pbmcvP3JlZktleT12VlBEOVpkTk1xJg%3D%3D&css=L2Nzcy9ub3Quc2V0LmNzcw%3D%3D). How to submit Blackberry Keys Order Form. How to do I received **Client-RDK.csj and Client-PBDT.csj** files.

Comment: If it asks you to enter your blackberry ID, then enter it.  You'll need to sign up for one if you don't have it yet.  What is your question here?

Comment: Same issue for me. "When I selected the First CheckBox for BlackBerry Keys Order Form, it is automatically point to another links". Help me, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is my understanding that the 2 .csj files are required to sign and port an Android application to the Blackberry Playbook Tablet, which does not currently run the Blackberry 10 OS.

The file you are looking for to sign the Android application for Blackberry 10 devices is a file with the .csk extension. (Filename: bbidtoken.csk)

I believe you do need to Sign-in with/Create a Blackberry ID to Access the Blackberry Jam Zone (Developer Portal).

After you have successfully signed into the Jam Zone, you will be asked to **Create a Blackberry ID Token** by entering a password into the available fields. Blackberry also notes that you can "*also request your BlackBerry ID token from the Deployment Setup Wizard in the BlackBerry Momentics IDE.*"

Comment: How to setup the Deployment Setup Wizard in the BlackBerry Momentics IDE. Add screen short is very useful for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

----------- Follow these steps which taken from [blackberry documentaion](http://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/cascades/getting_started/tools/signing_and_publishing.html)-----------------

1. Set up your development environment http://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/cascades/getting_started/setting_up.html

2.In Windows and Linux, click Window > Preferences. In Mac OS, click Momentics > Preferences.

3.Expand BlackBerry, and then select Signing.

4.Click BlackBerry Deployment Setup Wizard.

5.Follow the steps in the wizard to configure your BlackBerry ID token.